# Are these two database queries logically equivalent?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a query with an `OR` that runs poorly (i.e. a cost of 138 units):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE (FirstName LIKE 'Ian%') OR (LastName LIKE 'Boyd%')
```

But this query that returns the same runs much better (i.e. 0.6 units):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE (FirstName LIKE 'Ian%')

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE (LastName LIKE 'Boyd%')
```

These two queries are logically equivalent or identical--from the standpoint of what information I'm asking the relational database engine for. But if that's the case, the modern sophisticated query optimizer should understand all this, and not run the query any differently. And yet it does; which we know we can all chalk up to quirky query optimizers. So maybe they're **not** equivalent.

Are these two database queries logically equivalent?

```
CREATE TABLE Customers 
( 
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE INDEX IX_Customers_FirstName ON Customers (FirstName);
CREATE INDEX IX_Customers_LastNmae  ON Customers (LastName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are logically identical assuming that `customers` has no duplicate rows.  This is a reasonable assumption.

The `UNION` version is faster probably because the SQL engine can use indexes for the `LIKE` patterns -- they don't begin with a wildcard.

A faster and almost equivalent version is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Ian%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE LastName LIKE 'Boyd%' AND FirstName NOT LIKE 'Ian%';
```

The only issue here is if `FirstName` is `NULL`.  In that case, the logic would filter out even matching last names.  An exact equivalent needs to take this into account:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Ian%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE LastName LIKE 'Boyd%' AND
      (FirstName NOT LIKE 'Ian%' OR FirstName IS NULL);
```

These versions should be faster because they use `UNION ALL` and not `UNION`.  The latter incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  However, the `WHERE` clause removes those duplicates without having to look across rows.

Answer (score 1):

The forms of the two queries do not have the same semantics in general -- although it might need a more complex example to demonstrate a different result.

The first form (with `OR`) has `SELECT ...` but not `SELECT DISTINCT ...`. So it [might produce duplicate rows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Overview). (See references 5, 6 at that link.)

The second form has `... UNION ...` but not `... UNION ALL ...`. So it [must not produce duplicate rows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#UNION_operator), even though the individual `SELECT ...`s are not `DISTINCT`.

OTOH if that were the only difference with your particular schema on your particular DBMS with its particular configuration, I'd expect the `UNION` (not `ALL`) form to perform worse, because it needs to de-dup.